# Arduino, HC SR-04 distance sensor wrong output

Tags: arduino, distance, sensors

my name is Dmitrij and I wanted to connect HC-SR04 to Arduino so that I can measure the distance.
The problem is that the sensor is sending 4-5 right results and then 5-6 wrong ones in a row.

I've tried to replace Arduino and the sensor it didn't help.
At the end while I was writing this I kinda solved the problem.
The sensor was getting 5 Volt from external powersuply module (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkr9B.png) after I connected sensor to Arduino 5V everything was working Fine.
Is there a way to fix this somehow?

```
int echo = 8;
int trig = 9;
float duration, distance;

void setup() {

  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW); 
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) * 0.0344;
  Serial.print("Distance = ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
  delay(500);
```

}

Thats the output of the sensor when it was directed on the wall.
The real Distance is around 15-16 cm and i don't understand why does it output something else also.

```
Distance = 15.70 cm
Distance = 15.70 cm
Distance = 15.65 cm
Distance = 15.70 cm

Distance = 3.92 cm
Distance = 2.25 cm
Distance = 1.67 cm
Distance = 0.48 cm
Distance = 0.55 cm
Distance = 6.73 cm

Distance = 15.65 cm
Distance = 15.65 cm
Distance = 15.65 cm
Distance = 15.65 cm

Distance = 4.11 cm
Distance = 2.27 cm
Distance = 1.50 cm
Distance = 0.50 cm
Distance = 0.50 cm
Distance = 6.33 cm
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how curvy your scanned surface is, some times it can give you the wrong information, try scanning a flat surface and take a look your output will be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow [these steps](http://andrewjkramer.net/tag/hc-sr04/) ? I had same problem and I connected trig and echo pin as shown in link and worked.

Don't forget that you have to download [NewPing library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing/#Download)

If not worked, you should check all the cables.